# Semantic Role Labeling System Using SVM

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, feature-selection, semantic-analysis

Can anyone please tell me a working SRL(Semantic Role Labeling) based on SVM classifier?
Python or Java preferred.

My intention is to learn how the features in the sentences are represented as vectors, given a predicate verb.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Semantic Role Labeling` is not a simple problem, you can't solve it using a black-box solution. You should go through different steps where you have different choices.

As first guess, you can check [ProbBank (Ntlk/Python)](http://www.nltk.org/howto/propbank.html), [Senna](http://ml.nec-labs.com/senna/), [unified verb index](http://verbs.colorado.edu/verb-index/index.php). These r good projects to check. But non of these use svm.